# Auto rotate screen feature issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am facing one problem in my application, when i checked settings --> Display --> Auto-rotate screen and run my application in which all activities will display in landscape mode, so when i launch one acivity from other activity and rotate the device in vertical form and comes back to the previous activity upon click on button, in buton click event i am finish the activity which will bring previous activity on top,but it looses all its previuos configured data but when i unchecked device's Auto-rotate screen option it keeps the previous state of activity.

so not sure , why this behavior occurs?

Please help me to resolve it.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to all your activities in **AndroidManifest.xml** to override the orientation change manually

Comment: For ICS Devices he would also need to add "screenSize" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: I already added sndroid:configchanges = "orientation, but still i am unable to achieve the desire functionality.

Comment: can you post a sample project with one of your activity so that i can see what else is avoiding you to achieve this

Comment: Thanks Waqas, now it is working, i made one silly mistake because of that it was not working. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2):

Configuration Changes like an orientation change will lead to a recreation of your activity unless you specifically handle these events yourself.
Read the relevant documentation for more info.

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html
2. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Answer (score 0):

when you rotate the screen , android activity is recreated so it loses all the previous state. to avoid this situation  you can do the following

1. Stop recreation ( Just define android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ) in android menifest file.
2. Use following to handler orientation .

   ```
    @Override
           public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
               super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }
   ```

If layouts are different in portrait mode as well as in landscape mode so you should handle the  orientation